# Singleton mock object is not getting set in setInstance method

Tags: java, unit-testing, singleton, easymock

Hi I am trying to unit test my service class Which is using a Dao and Transaction manager class .Both the Dao and Transacion Manager classes are singleton. I am trying to create a mock object of these classes using a static setInstance method in each of these classes and then getting the object by getInstance method.
I was able to do that for transaction manager class but I am not able to do it for Dao.

```
  public class MusicPlayerDaoImpl implements MusicPlayerDao{
  private static MusicPlayerDaoImpl musicPlayerDao;

public static MusicPlayerDaoImpl getInstance(){
    if(musicPlayerDao==null){
        synchronized (MusicPlayerDaoImpl.class) {
            if(musicPlayerDao==null){
                musicPlayerDao = new MusicPlayerDaoImpl();
            }

        }
        musicPlayerDao = new MusicPlayerDaoImpl();
    }
    System.out.println("inside get instance of musicPlayerDao class"+musicPlayerDao);
    return musicPlayerDao;
}


public static void setInstance(MusicPlayerDaoImpl dao){
    System.out.println("inside set instance of MusicPlayerDaoImpl");
    musicPlayerDao = dao;
}

    //methods to perform db operations.
```

}

this setInstance method is not working for Dao class.Whereas it works fine for transactionmanager class. 
           public class TransactionManagerImpl implements TransactionManager{

```
private static ThreadLocal<Transaction> threadLocal = new ThreadLocal<Transaction>();

private static TransactionManagerImpl transactionManager;

public static TransactionManagerImpl getInstance(){
    if(transactionManager==null){
        synchronized (TransactionManagerImpl.class) {
            if(transactionManager==null){
                transactionManager = new TransactionManagerImpl();
            }

        }
        transactionManager = new TransactionManagerImpl();
    }
    System.out.println("inside get instance of transaction manager class"+transactionManager);
    return transactionManager;
}

public static void setInstance(TransactionManagerImpl manager){
    System.out.println("inside set instance of transaction manager");
    transactionManager = manager;
}
 //methods like begin,commit,rollback
}
```

My test class:
          @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(MusicPlayerDaoImpl.class)
public class MusicPlayerServiceTest {

```
private MusicPlayerDaoImpl dao;
private MusicPlayerServiceImpl service;
private TransactionManagerImpl transactionManager;

@Before
public void setUp() throws SQLException, NotSupportedException, SystemException, SecurityException, IllegalStateException, RollbackException, HeuristicMixedException, HeuristicRollbackException {
    this.service = MusicPlayerServiceImpl.getInstance();
    suppressConstructor(MusicPlayerDaoImpl.class);
    mockStatic(MusicPlayerDaoImpl.class);
    suppressConstructor(TransactionManagerImpl.class);
    mockStatic(TransactionManagerImpl.class);
    this.dao = createMock(MusicPlayerDaoImpl.class);
    this.transactionManager = createMock(TransactionManagerImpl.class);
    MusicPlayerDaoImpl.setInstance(this.Dao);
    TransactionManagerImpl.setInstance(this.transactionManager);
    Song song = new Song();
    Album album = new Album();
    Genre genre = new Genre();
    album.setAlbumName("i hate luv storys");
    genre.setGenreName("bollywood");
    song.setTitle("Bahara");
    song.setRating(4);
    song.setAlbum(album);
    song.setGenre(genre);
    EasyMock.expect(this.dao.getSong("Bahara")).andReturn(song);
    EasyMock.replay(this.dao);
    this.transactionManager.begin();
    EasyMock.expectLastCall();
    this.transactionManager.commit();
    EasyMock.expectLastCall();
    this.transactionManager.rollback();
    EasyMock.expectLastCall();
    EasyMock.replay(transactionManager);




}

@Test
public void getSongTest() throws SQLException, IllegalStateException,
        SecurityException, SystemException {
    String title = "Bahara";

    Song returnSong = this.service.getSong(title);
    System.out.println("Return song:----->"+returnSong.getAlbum().getAlbumName());
    assertTrue(returnSong.getTitle() == title);
}
```

}

I am getting a null pointer exception saying dao object is null .I am not getting where did I go wrong. Please help.

Comment: You never call `MusicPlayerDaoImpl.getInstance()`, instead you are calling `MusicPlayerServiceImpl.getInstance()`.

Comment: You wrote `MusicPlayerDaoImpl.setInstance(this.Dao);` - is that a misprint?  If not, it should probably be `MusicPlayerDaoImpl.setInstance(this.dao);`